# how can i interchange of two elements in html via js or jquery on click one of them?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<a href="javascript:" id="highLowRating" tabindex="0">
<a href="javascript:" id="lowHighRating" tabindex="1">
```

```
$('#lowHighRating').click(function(){
    // interchange with highLowRating" and if already then do nothing. 
});
$('#highLowRating').click(function(){
    // interchange with lowHighRating" and if already then do nothing.
});
```

I need to interchange the positions of the links if i click any one of them and if they already on their corresponding position then do nothing,i tried the `.toggle()` but its always changing the position,
am little confused here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) and [`insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/) to inserting element after/before another element.

```js
$("#highLowRating, #lowHighRating").click(function(){
    var index = $(this).index() - 1;
    if (index != $(this).attr("tabindex")){
        if (index == 0)
            $(this).insertAfter($(this).siblings("a"));
        else
            $(this).insertBefore($(this).siblings("a"));
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:" id="lowHighRating" tabindex="1">B</a>
<a href="javascript:" id="highLowRating" tabindex="0">A</a>
```

Comment: it does nothing, the `a` remains where it was at the beginning.

Comment: What is meaning of `it does nothing`? I work in snippent.

Comment: it always re positioning the `a` whether i click on already re positioned item.
If "A" is top then clicking on "A" will remains there.When i click on "B" then A replaced by B and B by A, Then when i Click on "B" then do nothing,We have to capture only Second link every time

Comment: i click on "B" then it replaces the "A" but after that nothing happen on click of "A" or "B"

Comment: You said `if they already on their corresponding position then do nothing`

Comment: i said the change will happen on click on every second position `a`

Comment: I can't understand what is your meaning and what you want.

Comment: This snippet is working like it should.However, the logic i implemented by using your snippet is worked now.Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" value="click" />
<p class="one">one</p>
<p class="two">two</p>
```

**Javascript**

```
$.fn.swap = function (elem) {
    elem = elem.jquery ? elem : $(elem);
    return this.each(function () {
        $(document.createTextNode('')).insertBefore(this).before(elem.before(this)).remove();
    });
};

$('.one').on('click', function () {
    alert(true);
});

$('input').click(function () {
    $('.one').swap('.two');
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/TVjnr/)

Comment: need to click on the `a` but not the external button